# How to make Ext.form.Combobox cannot input "dirty" data

Tags: extjs, combobox

Do we have any way to make an Ext.form.Combobox cannot input the data which is not in combobox's store?
It means that user can type to field for filter items quickly, but they cannot input the "dirty" data outside of the combobox's store? Does ExtJS support this feature by configuring properties or we have to customize it?!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configuring your combobox with the `editable:false` and `forceSelection:true` should suffice

Answer (score 0):

combo has 2 variables (like `<select>`) value and display. Even you set `editable:true` what is default and allow you to write in combo, whatever you write it should mach display in order to set value...

In you case wiget of TextField with autosuggest (not need to AJAX) would work